# cmake not finding Qt4

Tags: qt, compiler-construction, cmake

Since 4.8.0 is out, I've reinstalled Qt, and now I want to use cmake too. To make cmake work, I remember having to add the mingw bin folder (`QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3`) to PATH back in Qt4.7.3, so I guessed that there would be a similar folder in `QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0` now but this is not the case. My question is, does anybody else have experience with setting up Qt and cmake? I could use some help right now, as I've googled for a bit and was unable to find any ways to make cmake work.

When trying to build, I get this well known message:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:91 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find Qt4 (missing: QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE QT_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:252 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1171 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure all I had to do was make sure my QT_ROOT environment variable was set (C:\Qt\4.8.0\ on my machine).

Comment: @tmpearce: In CMakeLists.txt you mean? If not, could you please add how to do this?

Comment: I'm going off the "c:\..." path to assume you're in windows. From the right-click-on-"My Computer" context-menu, you can find your way to "Environment Variables".  Google it if you need more help, I don't have Windows at home here.  Once you're in there, you can create a new Environment Variable ("PATH" is usually one, as an example) if you need to (the one I described in my first comment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I found out what was the problem, and I think I should have known before. I simply added `C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\bin` to my PATH variable. It may be useful to note that, in a default 4.8.0 install, qmake is located in `C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\bin` as opposed to `C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw\bin` in 4.7.3. Notice the difference; `msvc2010` vs `mingw`. It's actually glaringly obvious, as `msvc2010` was the only folder in that directory.

I didn't try skyhisi's answer as it was no longer needed, but I'm guessing that it's another correct (if not better) way to make cmake work.

Answer (score 8):

You just need to set the path to qmake in `QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE`, and then cmake can use `qmake -query` to find all the other paths it needs (similar to pkg-config on Linux).

Steps for building a project using Qt and CMake usually are:

1. Check out / create project source folder
2. Create build folder outside the project folder
3. Start Qt command prompt / `cmd` and `cd` into build folder e.g. `cd build\project`
4. Run cmake or cmake-gui passing path to source folder e.g. `cmake-gui ..\..\source\project`
5. Set any variables, such as `QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE` and `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`
6. Run your build tool, or run `cmake --build .`

Comment: VTK instructions say to use flag `-DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:PATH=/path/to/qmake`, but this isn't working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into the same problem... Take a look into findQt4.cmake

```
FIND_PROGRAM(QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE NAMES qmake qmake4 qmake-qt4 qmake-mac PATHS
   "[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Trolltech\\Qt3Versions\\4.0.0;InstallDir]/bin"
   "[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Trolltech\\Versions\\4.0.0;InstallDir]/bin"
   "[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Trolltech\\Versions\\${qt_install_version};InstallDir]/bin"
   $ENV{QTDIR}/bin
   DOC "The qmake executable for the Qt installation to use")
```

You can either alter registry keys, or, I personally prefer deleting all those keys altogether and modify $ENV{QTDIR} variable. Good luck.

Comment: Many thanks! I've just uninstalled 4.8.5-vs2010 and installed 4.8.5-mingw, and the installers screwed up something. I traced the `findQt4.cmake` file, but didn't find the issue. Your post pointed me to the `Versions` in HKCU, which I found .. empty. It turned out that somehow the installer has put the entry under a wrong account! I'm perfectly sure that I run the installer as 'me,myself', not at the second desktop. Anyways, I moved the `Versions` from that-second-account to mine, and the cmake now finds Qt4 properly. Also, it's notable that putting the keys globally at HKLM doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem for a slightly different reason. Maybe this will help someone else:

I uninstalled Qt 4.8.3 and then installed qt 4.8.4. Based on Slava's answer I discovered that CMake is getting the value of $(qt_install_version} from:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Trolltech\\Versions\\DefaultVersion]
```

This was still set to 4.8.3 even though all the other registry entries were updated to 4.8.4. Changing the value of the DefaultVersion key to 4.8.4 fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved providing the path to qmake,

```
 QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE   /opt/qt-4.8.7/bin/qmake
```

On Mac, while the binaries are saved in `/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.7/bin`
the required qmake required as value of QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE is, for my OS, stored in the path `/opt/qt-4.8.7/bin/qmake` . Hope this help as well.