# CMake, Qt and CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH

Tags: qt, cmake

I found a great answer on how to get find the executable files in Qt with CMake, [cmake not finding Qt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933939/cmake-not-finding-qt4)

How do you use CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH? I tried it out, but I got an error:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../cmake_modules)

project(vrvu)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH <--- this is where I'm getting an error
 C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\bin)find_package(Qt4 COMPONENTS QtCore QtGui QtOpenGL REQUIRED)
include(${QT_USE_FILE})
find_package(Coin3 REQUIRED)
find_package(Quarter REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(bullet-2.77)
add_subdirectory(starlight)

file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp" "*.cxx" "*.h" "*.hpp")

include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${QT_INCLUDE_DIR} ${COIN_INCLUDE_DIR} ${QUARTER_INCLUDE_DIR} "./bullet-2.77/src" "./starlight")
link_directories(${QT_LIB_DIR} ${COIN_LINK_DIRECTORIES} ${QUARTER_LINK_DIRECTORIES})

add_definitions(${QT_DEFINITIONS} ${COIN_DEFINITIONS} ${QUARTER_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable(vrvu ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(vrvu ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${COIN_LIBRARIES} ${QUARTER_LIBRARIES} LinearMath BulletCollision starlight)
```

Sorry for the long code....thanks!

Comment: Why the downvote with no explanation?  Not helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

I'm not sure if it's just a typo but you can't just append the instruction to set `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` to the end of the `find_package` command, you need a separate `set` command:

```
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH "C:\\QtSDK\\Desktop\\Qt\\4.8.0\\msvc2010\\bin")
find_package(Qt4 COMPONENTS QtCore QtGui QtOpenGL REQUIRED)
```

Note that the path specified needs the separators to be escaped if you're using backslashes.  Alternatively, you can use a single forward slash in place of the double backslash, even on Windows.  Putting the path in quotes has no effect in this case, but it's a good habit to get into in case the path contains spaces.

Setting [`CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH) extends the list of paths CMake tries when doing `find_path` and `find_file` calls only.  This will be useful to the `find_package` call, but even more so in this case might be to set [`CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH) which extends the seach paths for all `find_XXX` commands.  It does mean you'd need to strip "\bin" from the path, since it's appended to the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` when searching for executables:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\QtSDK\\Desktop\\Qt\\4.8.0\\msvc2010")
```

Next, `file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp" "*.cxx" "*.h" "*.hpp")`.  While this isn't actually an error, generally it's frowned upon to use this technique to create a list of source files since if a file is added or deleted to the source tree, CMake will have no "knowledge" and won't re-run.  The recommended method is to add each source file by hand to the CMakeLists.txt, so that an addition or deletion will automatically cause CMake to re-run.

Also, "`SOURCES`" is a poor choice of variable name since it also represents a property of CMake targets.

Another frowned-upon practice is the use of [`link_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3alink_directories).  The documentation indicates why it's not usually needed, which should be the case here.

The `add_definitions` line too may be unnecessary.  Qt does define definitions, but they have already been added when you did `include(${QT_USE_FILE})` (see [the documentation for FindQt4](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#module%3aFindQt4)), so you're adding them twice here.  I'm not familiar with Coin3 or Quarter, but they may not actually generate any required preprocessor definitions.  You could check their contents by adding:

```
message("COIN_DEFINITIONS: ${COIN_DEFINITIONS}")
message("QUARTER_DEFINITIONS: ${QUARTER_DEFINITIONS}")
```

temporarily (after the corresponding `find_package` calls).  If these are empty, you can delete the `add_definitions` call.

Assuming the variables `${COIN_LIBRARIES}` and `${QUARTER_LIBRARIES}` specify the full paths to these libs, then I think you should be good to go.